# Regular expression in Python won't match end of a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm just learning Python, and I can't seem to figure out regular expressions.

```
r1 = re.compile("$.pdf")
if r1.match("spam.pdf"):
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

I want this code to print 'yes', but it obstinately prints 'no'. I've also tried each of the following:

```
r1 = re.compile(r"$.pdf")

r1 = re.compile("$ .pdf")

r1 = re.compile('$.pdf')

if re.match("$.pdf", "spam.pdf")

r1 = re.compile(".pdf")
```

Plus countless other variations. I've been searching for quite a while, but can't find/understand anything that solves my problem. Can someone help out a newbie?

Comment: this has nothing to do with python... you need to do a tutorial on regex's ...

Comment: Intro to regular expressions... http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/regex.html

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You've tried all the variations except the one that works. The `$` goes at the *end* of the pattern.  Also, you'll want to escape the period so it actually matches a period (usually it matches any character).

```
r1 = re.compile(r"\.pdf$")
```

However, an easier and clearer way to do this is using the string's `.endswith()` method:

```
if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
    # do something
```

That way you don't have to decipher the regular expression to understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew it had to be something simple!

Comment: Hmm, sorry, but it's still returning 'no'.

Comment: You're probably using `.match()` to check to see whether it matches. You want `.search()` since `.match()` only checks at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @user1634426 You probably want to use re.search rather than re.match.

Comment: How do you modify this to check multiple extensions? Something like: 
`filename.endswith("html|css|js")`

Comment: This is very late (sorry for missing it) `.endswith()` accepts a tuple of strings to match any of those provided. `filename.endswith((".html", ".css", ".js"))`

Comment: @kindall of course, python. Every programming langauge matches just the specified pattern, python must have its own logic :\

Answer (score 33):

### Behaviour of `re.match()` and `re.search()`

There is one significant difference: [`re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) checks **the beginning** of string, you are most likely looking for [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search).

Comparison of both methods is clearly shown in the Python documentation chapter called "[*search() vs. match()*](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match)"

### Special characters in regular expression

Also the meaning of characters in regular expressions is different than you are trying to use it (see [Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for details):

- `^` matches the beginning:

  > (Caret.) Matches the start of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline.
- `$` matches the end:

  > Matches the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string, and in `MULTILINE` mode also matches before a newline. foo matches both ‘`foo`’ and ‘`foobar`’, while the regular expression `foo$` matches only ‘`foo`’. More interestingly, searching for foo.$ in 'foo1\nfoo2\n' matches ‘`foo2`’ normally, but ‘`foo1`’ in `MULTILINE` mode; searching for a single `$` in '`foo\n`' will find two (empty) matches: one just before the newline, and one at the end of the string.

### Complete answer

The solution you are looking for may be:

```
import re
r1 = re.compile("\.pdf$")  # regular expression corrected
if r1.search("spam.pdf"):  # re.match() replaced with re.search()
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

which checks, if the string ends with "`.pdf`". Does the same as kindall's answer with `.endswith()`, but if kindall's answer works for you, choose it (it is cleaner as you may not need regular expressions at all).

Answer (score 8):

### Your Question

`$` means "end of string". So, you need a regex like `\.pdf$` to match:

1. A dot (`.`), escaped because it is a special character in regular expressions.
2. String "`pdf`"
3. End of string.

### Further Reading

Regular expressions go beyond languages, Python or others, so you should read some tutorials about them firstly. Consider [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info). This is not a Python question actually, it is a fundamental regular expression question.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `$.pdf` says "find the end of the string, then find any character and beyond the any character beyond the end of the string, find a p, a d and an f".

As written, it cannot sensibly match anything.

However, `pdf$` would match.

In this specific case, you probably also want to do a `search` rather than `match`, as I believe match is inherently anchored at the start of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 quick alternatives:

- `re.match(pattern='.*pdf$', string='filename.pdf')`

  Using this solution we must specify that we don't care about how the string begins. But we cannot omit the expression at the beginning.
  When using `re.match()` you must be sure to provide a regex valid for the whole string i.e. since index 0 see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#match-versus-search
- `re.search(pattern='\.pdf$', string='filename.pdf')`

  We don't care about how the string begins, we're just searching a string which ends with the extension

Answered have been already accepted but I've personnaly needed to check the official documentation to be clear with that.

Answer (score -1):

```
#This will work for regular expression
r1 = re.compile(r".+\.pdf$")
if r1.match("spam.pdf"):
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
#alternative soln
if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no
```

Comment: What does this add that the accepted answer does not already have?

Comment: r1 = re.compile("\.pdf$")  this would not accept strings like 'filename.pdf' only will accept the pattern ".pdf" but                                                                                                                                         r1 = re.compile(r".+\.pdf$") this would                                                                                          filename.endswith(".pdf") this is allright