# Python | Pandas | Objects | Convert to Integer or Float

Tags: python, pandas, object, types, integer

**Overview:**

I have scrapped some data off a website, put into a Pandas DataFrame but for some reason, I can't seem to convert the Data Type from an Object to an Integer or Float (for the point of this, either is fine).

I have looked through a few posts which have thankfully helped me get here, but for some reason, everything I try doesn't seem to work

**A sample of the Dataset:**

```
Condition_Type  State   Price      Year    Make         Model
In Stock        SA      $24,654    2017    Mazda        3
Used Car        VIC     $23,162    2016    Holden       Trax
Used Car        VIC     $15,777    2011    Volkswagen   Tiguan
Used Car        VIC     $12,634    2012    Volkswagen   Polo
In Stock        VIC     $70,501    2017    Volkswagen   Amarok
```

**What I have attempted so far:**

```
df["Price"] = df["Price"].str.replace("$","").astype(int)
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

```
df["Price"] = df["Price"].astype(str).astype(int)
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

```
pd.Series(df["Price"]).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.

```
pd.to_numeric(df["Price"], errors='coerce')
```

Returns NaN

```
pd.to_numeric(df["Price"], errors='ignore')
```

Values stay as objects

```
df["Price"] = df["Price"].astype(np.int64, inplace=True)
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

This last one has worked in the past, but for some reason, it isn't working on this data-set.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need escape value `$` first and then replace with `,` to empty string with [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df["Price"] = df["Price"].replace(["\$", ','],"", regex=True).astype(int)
print (df)
  Condition_Type State  Price  Year        Make   Model
0       In Stock    SA  24654  2017       Mazda       3
1       Used Car   VIC  23162  2016      Holden    Trax
2       Used Car   VIC  15777  2011  Volkswagen  Tiguan
3       Used Car   VIC  12634  2012  Volkswagen    Polo
4       In Stock   VIC  70501  2017  Volkswagen  Amarok

print (df['Price'].dtypes)
int32
```

Comment: This worked (thank you!) - can you explain why? You're replacing the $ sign with a comma - what is the "" doing in the code? I haven't done much work with Regular Expressions, but keen to learn more. I want to understand the why rather than you just give me the answer (which I appreciate a lot)

Comment: No, I dont replace by comma. I replace `$` and `,` to empty string.

Comment: Hard question how better understand regex. It is really huge area. But here need only escape `$` - it means in regex [end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12187814/2901002)

Comment: That makes sense - I've always used replace with one argument; not two. That's pretty cool! And regex = True is just finding a match for the '$' and ','? Thanks for helping me!

Comment: regex=True means find substrings define in `[]`.